# 'Column' object is not callable" - ge le gt lt methods

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements, typeerror

I have a dataframe and I'm trying to filter based on `end_date` if it's `>=` or `<` a certain date.

However, I'm getting a "not callable" error.

```
line 148, in <module>
    df_s1 = df_x.filter(df_x[\"end_date\"].ge(lit(\"2022-08-17\")))
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable"
```

Here is my code:

```py
df_x = df_x.join(df_di_meet, trim(df_x.application_id) == trim(df_di_meet.application_id), "left")\
             .select (df_x["*"], df_di_meet["end_date"])
             
# ... Cast end_date to timestamp ...end_date format looks like 2013-12-20 23:59:00.0000000
df_x = df_x.withColumn("end_date",(col("end_date").cast("timestamp")))

# ... Here df_s1 >= 2022-08-17
df_s1 = df_x.filter(df_x["end_date"].ge(lit("2022-08-17")))

#... Here df_s2 < 2022-08-17
df_s2 = df_x.filter(df_x["end_date"].lt(lit("2022-08-17")))
```

What I'm trying to do is check additional logic as well like the code below, but since it's not working with a `when` clause I decided to break down the dataframes and check each one separately. Is there an easier way, or how could I get the below code to work?

```py
df_x = df_x.withColumn("REV_STAT_TYP_DES", when((df_x.review_statmnt_type_desc == lit("")) & (df_x("end_date").ge(lit("2022-08-17"))), "Not Released")
                                           when((df_x.review_statmnt_type_desc == lit("")) & ((df_x("end_date").lt(lit("2022-08-17"))) | (df_x.end_date == lit(""))), "Not Available")
                                           .otherwise(None))
```

Comment: You can reference columns using `col('end_date')` , example - `df_x.filter(col('end_date').ge(lit("2022-08-17")))`

Comment: @AJR Where do those `.ge` and `.lt` come from? You don't have these methods neither in Column class, nor in DataFrame class in PySpark.

Comment: `.ge, .le, .ge, .lt `are pandas methods. In pyspark use `<, >`. See my and how I use `>` and `gt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There are attempts](https://github.com/palantir/pyspark-style-guide#refactor-complex-logical-operations) to make difficult code look cleaner. According to those recommendations, conditional statements may be better understood and maintained if they were separated into different variables. Look at how I've added `isnull` to some of the variables - it would have been a lot more difficult if they were not refactored into separate variables.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

no_review = (F.col("review_statmnt_type_desc") == "") | F.isnull("review_statmnt_type_desc")
no_end_date = (F.col("end_date") == "") | F.isnull("end_date")
not_released = no_review & (F.col("end_date") >= F.lit("2022-08-17"))
not_available = no_review & ((F.col("end_date") < F.lit("2022-08-17")) | no_end_date)
```

Also, you don't need the `otherwise` clause if it returns `null` (its the default behaviour).

```py
df_x = df_x.withColumn(
    "REV_STAT_TYP_DES",
    F.when(not_released, "Not Released")
     .when(not_available, "Not Available")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

df_x("end_date") --> This is wrong way of accessing a spark dataframe column. That's why python is assuming it as a callable and you are getting that error.

df_x["end_date"] --> This is how you should access the column (or df_x.end_date)

**UPDATE**:

Now only noticed ,  .ge() or .le() kind of methods  won't work with spark dataframe column objects. You can use any of the below ways of filtering:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df_s1 = df_x.filter(df_x["end_date"] >='2022-08-17')
# OR
df_s1 = df_x.filter(df_x.end_date>='2022-08-17')
# OR
df_s1 = df_x.filter(col('end_date')>='2022-08-17')
# OR
df_s1 = df_x.filter("end_date>='2022-08-17'")
# OR
# you can use df_x.where() instead of df_x.filter
```

Comment: Hi - I'm still getting the same issue even though I made the change. Any other suggestions??

Comment: @AJR : Updated the comments with solution. Before the error was "DataFrame object is not callable" , Now the error is "Column object is not callable". Both are different

Answer (score 0):

You probably got confused between pandas and pyspark. Anyway this is how you do it

DataFrame

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("2022-08-16",1),("2019-06-24",2),("2022-08-19",3)]).toDF("date","increment")#
```

Pyspark

```
df_x = df.withColumn('date', to_date('date'))
df_x.filter(col('date')>(to_date(lit("2022-08-17")))).show()
```

Pandas

```
df_x = df.toPandas()

df_s1 = df_x.assign(date= pd.to_datetime(df_x['date'])).query("date.gt('2022-08-17')", engine='python')
```

or

```
df_x[df_x['date']>'2022-08-17']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL style free form case/when syntax in the expr() function. That way it is portable also.

```
df_x = (df_x.withColumn("REV_STAT_TYP_DES",
         expr(""" case 
                  when review_statmnt_type_desc='' and  end_date >='2022-08-17' then 'Not Released'
                  when review_statmnt_type_desc='' and  ( end_date <'2022-08-17' or end_date is null ) then 'Not Available'
                  else null 
                 end 
           """)
```